# How to get Correct Subscription key for microsoft Translator API

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I have signed up for Azure's Translator Speech API then I have followed instruction from this url https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/translation/gettingstarted1/
but I am still getting the 401 message?

I have checked with both python and node scripts from https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator

Text Translation is working fine https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/PythonConsole/blob/master/MTPythonSampleCode/MTPythonSampleCode.py

Can you please guide me what I am doing wrong??

Thanks

Python Error code
[image: error code]

Node Error Code:
[image]

Comment: did you have any app id ? This service is free ?

Comment: yes bro, service is free. BTW I have activated Azure's free trial which gave me access to all APIs

Comment: You can't get session on service or your service app not activated yet !